# User register hook is not working in woocomerce register form

Tags: php, forms, user-registration

Hi guys I cannot access the user email even if I do a simple echo function. It doesn't show anything in the front, but when I hit some error and on the error page I can see the echo. What can cause this, any thoughts?

```
function send_coupon_to_freshly_registered_user($user_id) {
        $user = get_user_by('id',$user_id); //new line
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email); //changed line
        echo $user_email;
}
add_action('user_register', 'send_coupon_to_freshly_registered_user', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

`user_register` action hook is performed without any output, therefore you can't echo anything from it.

If you're looking to debug the output from this function, dump it to the error log.

```
function send_coupon_to_freshly_registered_user($user_id) {
        $user = get_user_by('id',$user_id); //new line
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email); //changed line
        error_log( print_r( $user_email, true ) ); // print_r the variable to error log.
}
add_action('user_register', 'send_coupon_to_freshly_registered_user', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Yes lol I got to know that after reading a few posts and docs haha but thanks it works.